# gpg on Debian 9.3 isn't finding any private keys only public ones

Tags: debian, gpg

Under Debian 8 I created (presumably, then with gpg 1 or 2.0) and published my key secring.gpg to a keyserver, the file is still under the directory ~/.gnupg/. But now with gpg 2.1:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys
```

has no output and attempts to sign something

```
gpg -s tmp.txt
```

fail with

```
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
```

Did I botch somehow the upgrade from Debian 8 to 9?  Should I have exported the secret key before upgrading and how can I import the "old" secret key into the "new" gpg?

**update 2018-03-01:**

The problem is simply that - somehow, sometime - my secring.gpg shrank to the size 0! :-/  Discovered it with the solution from Stephen Kitt, when trying to import

```
gpg --import-secret-keys secring.gpg
```

I got a message that my file contains no valid data.

Comment: Does it help at all if you install `gnupg1` and run `gpg1 --list-secret-keys`?

Comment: @StephenKitt Just did that, also with gpg1 --list-secret-key there's no output! :-/  I only see the public keys with gpg2 and gpg1...

Comment: OK, how big is `~/.gnupg/secring.gpg`? Do you have anything in `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d`? (The former is used by GPG 1 and 2.0, the latter by GPG 2.1.)

Comment: @StephenKitt there's nothing in private-keys-v1.d.  Regarding secring.gpg I've to check but there should be only on key included. Here's the corresponding puplic key: uid H. Dieter Wilhelm (Emacsite) <dieter@duenenhof-wilhelm.de> pub  2048R/8A39DBAE 2013-08-07

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GnuPG 2.1 no longer uses `~/.gnupg/secring.gpg`; instead, it uses separate files in ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d`, with the help of its agent. There should have been an automatic migration at some point, however there are a number of scenarios where that misses some information (including the case where a private key is added using GnuPG 1 *after* the 2.1 migration).

To resolve the issue, you should import your secret keyring:

```
gpg --import ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

You’ll find more useful information in [this handy GnuPG 2.1 migration guide](https://lelutin.ca/posts/Migrating_to_gpg2.1/), and in [the release notes](https://gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html).

(I think it’s also worth mentioning that your secret keyring should never be exported to a public server, and that GnuPG itself will try to prevent you from doing so; thus you can’t rely on external sources of information as backups of your secret keys.)

Comment: Didn't you mean --import-secret-keys?

Comment: I *think* `--import` is correct, GnuPG 2.1 doesn’t have an `--import-secret-keys` option any more — if you know better (*e.g.* if you tried `--import`, and it didn’t work, but `--import-secret-keys` did), I’d be grateful if you edited the answer accordingly!

Comment: @Stepen Kitt thanks for the hint, it seems that gpg 2.1 is still accepting --import-secret-keys ;-). Maybe for a backward compatibility reasons... (My import attempts didn't work with neither options, obviously.)

Comment: Oh I see, I hadn’t noticed your updated question :-/. A truncated `secring.gpg` is rather unexpected...

Comment: The truncation must have been around my debian updgrade from 7 to 8. in 2015 since this time I didn't use encryption any longer and the key was created in 2013...